# Weird Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get an error in live application sometimes.

Stack trace:

> at Tool.User_RequestSender.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\Site\Tool\User\RequestSender.aspx.cs:line 72 at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I tried again and again to run code om my machine but could not get same error.

Even i live code i get this issue once in while.

Page_Load Code in RequestSender.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.LoadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            this.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

LoadRequest() is as follows:

```
private void LoadRequest()
    {
        Credential credential;


            if (
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["typeOfrequest"]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["empUserId"]) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["applicationId"])
               )
            {
                // Get details of credentials
                credential = (new RequestManager()).GetCredential(this.EmpUserId, this.ApplicationId, (int)this.TypeOfrequest);
                this.applicaionRequest = new Request
                {
                    RequestType = this.TypeOfrequest,
                    RequestStatus = Enumerations.RequestStatus.Sent,
                    Application = credential.Application,

                    EmpUserId = credential.EmpUserId,
                    EmployeeId = credential.EmployeeId,
                    Username = credential.Username,

                    SenderAddress = Security.CurrentUser.Details.EmailAddress,
                    ReceiverAddress = (new Datastore.RequestStore()).GetReceiverAddress((int)this.TypeOfrequest, this.ApplicationId),
                    AddedBy = Security.CurrentUser.Details.UserId
                };
                    ucSendRequest.ApplicationRequest = applicaionRequest;

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Invalid request!");
                Response.End();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The fact that you've got a `catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is masking the original cause. Get rid of that catch block and you'll get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: what is ucSendRequest?

Comment: Exaclty...but I am not able to get error on my machine...Even if i remove try catch i am not getting any error or issue again on my machine...

Comment: @mihirj: It is user control

Comment: Catching an exception then issuing "throw ex" replaces the stacktrace which means you have less chance of finding out where your exception actually came from. If you need to rethrow an exception you've caught use "throw" on its own inside the catch block. If there is nothing in your catch block but the throw then you didn't need the catch block in the first place.

Comment: @user1181942 If you remove the redundant catch blocks then when the error occurs in live the next time you will have possibly a better understanding of where the error came from because you won't be throwing away the stack trace. Essentially, you'll have better information in your logs.

Comment: @ColinMackay: Sorry for the wrong code...I put the repeated try catch thing to check the issue...in actual live code there is no repeated try catch.. i have updated above code now:

Comment: @user1181942 and where is `RequestSender.aspx.cs:line 72` ?

Comment: @Aristos: it is "throw ex;" in Page_Load event

Comment: @user1181942 this what the rest users says you, remove that extra catch to find the line of the throw

Comment: @Aristos I got what everybody is saying.. but now I am not getting same error again. I have removed that extra catch.. Now my problem is that I am not able to get error but I know some but is there...I checked again and again for all values if there is anything null, but not getting anything.. Probably I should wait and watch..

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly states that smth is `null` during application execution.

To get any help you should either check for `null` values (`Request` in `LoadRequest()` can be a good candidate), or, better solution, to modify your catch blog to log which parameter caused application to crash.